# Search in Three-Dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have A Three-dimensional array. I was trying to search for a company by keywords

```
   $Platinum = array
        (
        array(
            "Name"        => "Art of Life",
            "description" => "a description",
            "keyword"     => array(
                "designing",
                "interior design websites",
            ),
        ),
        array(
            "Name"        => "Golden Art",
            "description" => "a description",
            "keyword"     => array(
                "designing",
                "design company",
                "design services",
            ),
        ),
    );
```

I tried this `print_r(array_search("designing", array_column($Platinum[0], 'keyword')));`
but didn't work.
How to search by keywords and get the name of the company if I found the keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code,

```
$arr = array_column($Platinum, 'keyword');
$current_key = '';
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    if(in_array('designing', $v)){
        $current_key = $k;
        break;
    }    
}
$company_name = $Platinum[$current_key]['Name'];
echo $company_name;die;
```

Give it a try, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

This function would do the job for you:

```
function find_company_by_keyword($companies, $search_keyword)
{
    $search_keyword = trim(strtolower($search_keyword));
    $results = [];

    foreach ($companies as $company) {
        $keyword_found = false;

        foreach ($company['keyword'] as $keyword) {
            if ($keyword_found) continue;

            $keyword = trim(strtolower($keyword));
            if ($keyword == $search_keyword) $results[] = $company;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Usage:

```
$results = find_company_by_keyword($Platinum,'designing');
```